# How can I make FireFox understand the correct height of my divs?

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9m1Lba6u/

This works on Google Chrome and Safari and shows all the numbers from 1 to last. But in FireFox it only shows until 99. Am I missing some thing in my style sheet?

here is a shorter version off my code:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #CDF1F4;
}
.main-content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #BEE4F4;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.side-bar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #E1BEF4;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

<div class="head"></div>
<div class="main-content"></div>
<div class="side-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple CSS2 approch (it require couple of more wrappers though)

HTML:

```
<div class="head"></div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="page-inner">
        <div class="main-content">first
            <br>1
            <br>2
            <br>3
            <br>4
            .....
            <br>99
            <br>100
            <br>
            <br>last
        </div>
        <div class="side-bar">first
            <br>1
            <br>2
            <br>3
            <br>4
            .....
            <br>99
            <br>100
            <br>
            <br>last
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body:before{
    content:'';
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
.head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #CDF1F4;
}
.page{position:relative;}
.page:after{content:''; display:block; clear:both;}
.page-inner{position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;}
.main-content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #BEE4F4;
    overflow: auto;
}
.side-bar {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #E1BEF4;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #F4BED6;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. using 2 nested dives was a good idea. by the way do you know why Firefox have problem with my first approach?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I didn't understand it fully, but it looked like  box-sizing was behaving differantly in Firefox. Thus to remove that proble I developed this solution which do not use any css3 or spacial code. It is just simple css trick.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
overflow: scroll;
```

in .main-content and .side-bar , It works for me

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me. I'm using Firefox 32 Mac OS. Adding overflow scroll makes an other problem. In windows you will get a really ugly scroll bar even if your content is not larger that page height so that's not the best solution.